# Regex match for new lines

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am trying to get the log statements in my code using java. I am using this regex:

```
Log\.[dD].*\);
```

Test data:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Construct product info");

test test test test 

Log.d(TAG, "Loading Product Id: %d, Version: %s",
    productInfo.getProductId(),
    productInfo.getProductVersion());

test test test test 

Log.d(TAG, "Loading Product Id: " +
    ProductId + "Version:" +
    Version);

test test test test
```

for some reason, regex is only picking up 1st line which is

```
Log.d(TAG, "Construct product info");
```

Correct output should be:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Construct product info");

Log.d(TAG, "Loading Product Id: %d, Version: %s",
    productInfo.getProductId(),
    productInfo.getProductVersion());

Log.d(TAG, "Loading Product Id: " +
    ProductId + "Version:" +
    Version);
```

https://regex101.com/r/OCl9dy/3

If I am not mistaken, regex should return all Log.[dD] statements that ends with );

Please let me know why it does not pick up others and how to fix this.

thanks

Comment: Use `(?s)Log\.[dD].*?\);`. Note it won't work when `);` is [not the function call end](https://regex101.com/r/uPTFZp/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
Log\.[dD][\s\S]*?\);
```

The two mistakes you made were:

- `.` does not match line endings. You should use something similar to `[\s\S]`, which matches everything.
- You need to match *lazily*, stop matching at the first `)` you see. So write `*?` instead of `*`.

Note that the regex won't work for things like `Log.d(TAG, "Construct (product); info");` because the first `);` is not the end of the method call. To match these, I suggest you write/use a parser.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCl9dy/4)

Comment: Note `Log\.[dD][\s\S]*?\);` won't work when `);` is [not the function call end](https://regex101.com/r/uPTFZp/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, I was just gonna add that.

Comment: thank you !! I understand why now. I have been trying to fix this on my own for last 6 hours